# How to click on the X icon to close the iframe using Seleniumv3 and Python3

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am having difficulty closing iframe popup on https://www.kariyer.net/
using python3.

[image: iframe]

When I try to inspect the code inside browser it looks like the link is inside an `<i>` tag and there are no `href` inside that tag. My guess is that it's a javascript link and I'm not much of a javascript guy at all.

I couldn't find anything on google cause every situation that comes up on google, seems include either a button or an `href` tag.

[image: iframe code inspection]

Since it's a live website, I am not sharing html code but if you need it please let me know.
I am fairly new to Selenium and any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So have you switched to the iframe first? (e.g. driver.switchTo().frame("id of the element") )

Comment: Yes, I switched to iframe. My problem is, I couldn't find the link to close iframe in HTML code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the url you have shared to `click()` on the **X** icon you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *frame to be available and switch to it* and then again induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.kariyer.net/")

  # xpath
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='sp-fancybox-iframe adaptive-resolution']")))

  # css_selector
  # WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.sp-fancybox-iframe.adaptive-resolution")))

  # xpath
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='element-content']/i[@class='fa fa-times element-close-button']"))).click()

  # css_selector
  # WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.element-content > i.fa.fa-times.element-close-button"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: kariyer]

Comment: I changed the executable_path to my /usr/ and it works. 
This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Out of curiosity if you don't mind me asking, Can we do this without xpath?

Comment: @user611811 Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Works great. I'm having trouble getting back to default content.Shouldn't I get back to it with `driver.switch_to.default_content()`? or am I missing something? By the way I am using your solution while I logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Code below waits frame and switch to it, then clicks to close button and switch back to main. See selectors I used if you have problems to locate them.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    .until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe.sp-fancybox-iframe")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("i.element-close-button").click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Most likely, you'll have to write custom handler to be able to skip different types of popups coming on first open the website. For example, you can put code above to try/catch to be able to skip without error if any other type of popup will appear.

Comment: Python. You need to import: `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`,
`from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait `,
`from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`